# Format Describe In SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle11g

I like a large linesize in SQL*Plus so that data doesn't wrap between lines.  The problem is that doing a describe on an object seems to be obligated to spread itself over the entire line size.  This makes it so that I can only see the name part without scrolling to the right.  What I want is one linesize for describes and a different line size for everything else.  To see what I mean run the following in SQL*Plus:

```
set linesize 100;
describe all_tab_columns; --Desired Output
select * from all_tab_columns where rownum<=1;
```

Then use a large line size.

```
set linesize 3000;
describe all_tab_columns;
select * from all_tab_columns where rownum<=1; --Desired Output
```

What I am asking may not be possible, so I'd also be interested in partial solutions.  Constantly changing the linesize is not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is stopping you from setting linesize?

```
set linesize 100; 
describe all_tab_columns;
set linesize 3000; 
select * from all_tab_columns where rownum<=1;
```

If you do this often, write SQL scripts to make it more convenient.

Comment: I created a script I can call using '@desc <objectname>' as follows:

Comment: set linesize 100;
describe &1;
set linesize 3000;

Answer (score 2):

I've got my own version of DESC as a package, so I do
exec DESCR('table_name');

Code is available [Here](http://sites.google.com/a/sydoracle.com/sydoracle/home/my_desc.pck?attredirects=0&d=1).

Comment: +1 I thought about doing this, but was hoping there was a simpler solution.  On the plus side I could put more information in the describe.